# How do I make dynamic classNames in an ember 2.0 component?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

For example: 
Ember components allow you to add a classNames array and those classes will be added to the main div of the component.
say we have this component called **new-div**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['container']
});
```

then if you inspect this component when rendered you will see:

```
<div id="ember595" class="ember-view container">
...
<div>
```

this is fine but my issue is what if i want to use this component as a fluid container sometimes and sometimes I might want to make it a jumbotron etc.

Is there a way to do this in the html and have the component.js apply it correctly?

```
{{new-div extra-classes='class1,class2'}}
```

then in the component.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: [this.get('class-names')]
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [classNameBindings](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_classNameBindings)

Comment: @Craicerjack `classNames` is not `classNameBindings`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add class names simply by specifying them inside the `class` attribute on your component:

```
{{new-div class="class1 class2"}}
```

Comment: isn't the attribute `classNames` or was this changed recently?

Comment: @ABot I think `class` works since they moved to htmlbars and it's a better option, but `classNames` still works too.

Answer (score 14):

The [@dmk'solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020515/316700) is the cleanest one, but if your scenario it is not working you can use [classNameBindings](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['getClassNames'],
  getClassNames: Ember.computed('extra-classes', function(){
    return this.get('extra-classes').replace(',', ' ');
  })
})
```

Comment: This one is great when you want the component to control its own class names.

Comment: this could just be `classNameBindings: ['myClassNames'],` where `myClassNames` is an attribute declared on the template. no computed property necessary (of course in your example it is because OP has a comma-delimited list).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adding too many classes, it's easy enough with class name bindings:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: [
    'foo:bar',
    'foo:baz',
  ],
});
```

And set the value of foo:

`{{new-div foo=true}}`

This will toggle on all the above class names.

See: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Component/properties/classNameBindings?anchor=classNameBindings

Of course, you could get tricky with computed properties and mapping an array. Also: I like to avoid assigning dynamic class names to components explicitly. Things become messy rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative one could use something like this

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
attributeBindings:  ['style'],

    style: function(){
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('class="foo bar"');
    }.property(),
});

// NOT sure on this one untested
export default Ember.Component.extend({
attributeBindings:  ['classNames'],

    classNames: function(){
        return 'foo bar';
    }.property(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using **ember-component-css**, you may want to try out the `join-classes` or the `local-class` attribute helper.

```
{{join-classes styles.myclass1 attributeValue}}
```

`attributeValue` can be a value from the component's controller (I mean `component.js`), or an item inside an `each` block.

If `styles.myclass1 = .class1`, and `attributeValue = .dummy`, then the selectors would be available as `.class1.dummy` in the **styles.css**.

```
local-class={{(concat "myclass-" myvalue)}}
```

If `myvalue = 'part'`, then with this, the generated classname would include `tree-to-component_myclass-part__sdfje2jbr2` (last part is generated id), and would be accessible in the stylesheet as `.myclass-part`.